# Fastest way to read just first line in a constantly updated file in C#

Tags: c#

I implemented this in VB by reading first line then calling `Seek #fileNo, 1`, which would return the cursor at the beginning of the file. Now I need to reimplement this in C#, and came up with the following:

```
while (isFileUpdated)
{
        lineUpdated = File.ReadAllLines(UPDATE_FILEPATH,Encoding.UTF8)[0];
        if (lastLineUpdated != lineUpdated)
        {
              lastLineUpdated = lineUpdated;
              ParseLine(lineUpdated);
        }
}
```

I read this is OK for small files, however ReadAllLines() seems to close the stream after it's done its job so this would reopen/close on each iteration. Probably not the most efficient solution.
I code in Java for Android. .NET isn't one of my strengths:) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use `ReadAllLines` since it will read all lines at once, use `ReadLines` instead. It will read the line one-by-one

Comment: The text file has only one short line.

Comment: if your file is only one line then use File.ReadAllText to avoid the array and just get an string

Comment: If the text file is only one short line, then it is *most likely* a small file (unless you have millions of characters in that line), isn't it?

Comment: I would use a FileWatcher to determine when the file is changed, and only read it when that fires... Reading a file constantly in a tight loops seems wrong.

Comment: My worries with the FileWatcher, when considering that options for VB, was that the program reading would be slower than the one updating, unable to keep up. Resulting in skipped update states.